# boost::program_options - how to handle multiple sections with the same name in INI file

Tags: c++, configuration-files, ini, boost-program-options

In a config like below; is there a way to handle individual sections.

I am looking for a way to validate individual "server" sections below, in a reliable manner.

```
[basic]
number_of_servers=3

[server]
ip=10.20.30.40
password=sdfslkhf    

[server]
ip=10.20.30.41
password=sdfslkhf

[server]
ip=10.20.30.42
password=sdfslkhf

[server]
password=sdfslkhf

[server]
ip=10.20.30.42
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using `boost::program_options` to parse a INI file, the option names *must* be prefixed by their enclosing section names.

In other words, sections are part of the option 'identifier', but I don't think you have a way to identify to *which* section a given `server.ip` variable belongs (and thus, which is the associated `server.password`).

I think you should consider [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/property_tree.html) (which also supports INI file parsing) for this task.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp120049504):

The option names are relative to the section names, so the following configuration file part:

```
  [gui.accessibility]
  visual_bell=yes
```

is equivalent to

```
  gui.accessibility.visual_bell=yes
```

But there is currently no way to distinguish sections with the same name.

UPDATE:

Qt's QSettings usually solves this by postfixing values (sections?) from an array with "/n". So you could use:

```
[server/0]
...
[server/1]
...
[server/2]
...
```